# can I pass a string in aoColumn in datatables in php

Tags: php, datatables

Instead of passing the value like `{'bSortable': false},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{'bSortable': false}` in `aoColumns` can I pass a string which is also containing the same value as above in datatables and php?
My Code is like:

```
var excluded_clmns_sorting = $('#sorting_val').val();
//the above variable returns {'bSortable': false},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{'bSortable': false}.
var oTable = $('#data-table').dataTable( {
       "sDom": 'CT<"clear">firtlip',
       "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": basePath+"/js/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [ {"sExtends": "csv","sFileName" : curpath+".csv","sButtonText": "Save to CSV","mColumns": "visible"} ]
         },
       "aoColumns" : [excluded_clmns_sorting]
 } );
```

In js Console it is showing `nCell is undefined`.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

//UPDATE
if I pass array in `excluded_clmns_sorting` variable and doing the following code:

```
var excluded_clmns_sorting = $('#sorting_val').val();
    var excluded_clmn_sorting = (excluded_clmns_sorting) ? excluded_clmns_sorting.split(",") : [];
    $.each(excluded_clmn_sorting, function (i) {
      excluded_clmn_sorting[i] = (excluded_clmn_sorting[i]);
    })

    var oTable = $('#data-table').dataTable( {
       "sDom": 'CT<"clear">firtlip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": basePath+"/js/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [ {"sExtends": "csv","sFileName" : curpath+".csv","sButtonText": "Save to CSV","mColumns": "visible"} ]

         },
         "aoColumns" : [excluded_clmn_sorting],
         "aoColumnDefs": [{
                            "bVisible": false,
                            "aTargets" : excluded_clmn
                         },
                      ],
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
       'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers'
    } );
```

Then in js Console it is showing only `oCol is undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

you can put a `array` in `aoCoumns` not `string`

`aoColumns`: If specified, then the length of this `array` must be equal to the number of `columns` in the original HTML table. Use 'null' where you wish to use only the default values and automatically detected options.

[read here](http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns)

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But length of the array is same as the number of column using in original html page. But still not working, while if I put the value of excluded_clmn_sorting directly in aoColumns then its working and if I put the variable(i.e excluded_clmn_sorting) in aoColumns then it is not working.

Comment: this is the value of excluded_clmn_sorting {'bSortable': false},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{'bSortable': false} and it is a string.

Comment: use this var excluded_clmn_sorting=["values","values","values"];

Comment: or put only null values in string(dont use bSortalbe inside string)

Comment: but for some columns it will be {'bSorta‌​ble': false}. Then what will do for that column?

Comment: what will the problem if not use as variable variable?

Comment: because I have so many pages and only one custom.js where the datatables initialization and customization are happening. Only I want to pass the different value  from different page.
If I override aoColumns in different page then I can do that and hope this problem will be solved.

Comment: so is there any process to declare a variable in aoColumns